# Mapping Nested Config Yaml to struct

Tags: go, struct, config, viper-go

I'm new to go and I'm using viper to load all my configs. What I currently have is YAML that looks like:

```
 countryQueries:
  sg:
    - qtype: gmap
      qplacetype: postal_code
    - qtype: gmap
      qplacetype: address
    - qtype: geocode
      qplacetype: street_address

  hk:
    - qtype: gmap
      qplacetype: postal_code
    - qtype: gmap
      qplacetype: address
    - qtype: geocode
      qplacetype: street_address
```

Please note that the country codes are dynamic. They could be added anytime for any country. How do I map this to a struct where technically speaking I can do:

```
for _, query := range countryQueries["sg"] { }
```

I tried to construct it myself by looping through it, but I'm stuck here:

```
for country, queries := range viper.GetStringMap("countryQueries") {
    // i cant seem to do anything with queries, which i wish to loop it
    for _,query := range queries {} // error here
}
```

Answer (score 8):

After done some reading realized that viper has it own unmarshaling capabilities which works great https://github.com/spf13/viper#unmarshaling

So here what i did

```
type Configuration struct {
    Countries map[string][]CountryQuery `mapstructure:"countryQueries"`
}

type CountryQuery struct {
    QType      string
    QPlaceType string
}

func BuildConfig() {
    viper.SetConfigName("configFileName")
    viper.AddConfigPath("./config")
    err := viper.ReadInConfig()
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("Error config file: %s \n", err))
    }

    var config Configuration

    err = viper.Unmarshal(&config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("Unable to decode Config: %s \n", err))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here some simple code with [go-yaml](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
    "log"
)

var data = `
countryQueries:
  sg:
    - qtype: gmap
      qplacetype: postal_code
    - qtype: gmap
      qplacetype: address
    - qtype: geocode
      qplacetype: street_address

  hk:
    - qtype: gmap
      qplacetype: postal_code
    - qtype: gmap
      qplacetype: address
    - qtype: geocode
      qplacetype: street_address
`

func main() {
    m := make(map[interface{}]interface{})

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", m)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to map your `yaml` structure to a strict golang `struct` you could make use of the [mapstructure](https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure) library to map the nested key/value pairs under each country.

For example:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/spf13/viper"
    "github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type CountryConfig struct {
    Qtype string
    Qplacetype string
}
type QueryConfig struct {
    CountryQueries map[string][]CountryConfig;
}
func NewQueryConfig () QueryConfig {
    queryConfig := QueryConfig{}
    queryConfig.CountryQueries = map[string][]CountryConfig{}
    return queryConfig
}
func main() {

    viper.SetConfigName("test")
    viper.AddConfigPath(".")
    err := viper.ReadInConfig()
    queryConfig := NewQueryConfig()
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic("error:", err)
    } else {
        mapstructure.Decode(viper.AllSettings(), &queryConfig)
    }
    for _, config := range queryConfig.CountryQueries["sg"] {

        fmt.Println("qtype:", config.Qtype, "qplacetype:", config.Qplacetype)
    }
}
```

Comment: After done somemore reading realized that Viper has its own unmarshaling which works like a charm so i decided to use that,

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml to serialize/deserialize YAML in Go.